# Coordinates of a point of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have $A(3,5), B(-1, -2)$ and $d:7x-6y+1=0$, and we have to find a point $C$ on $d$ such that area of triangle $ABC$ to be $1$.

I wrote an relation between $C's$ coordinates from $C$ belongs to $d$, and from area value I found height from $C$, $CC'$, and from that value i tried to get another relation between $C$
's coordinates but it get complicated.

Is there another approach to solve that?

Comment: Let $C(p,q)$ be the point on the line $d$. Then area of $\triangle ABC$ is given by the determinant $\frac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}3&5&1\\-1&-2&1\\p&q&1\end{vmatrix}$. Set this equal to $1$ to get one equation in $p$ and $q$, then use the line's equation (with $p,q$) to solve for $C$.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about that

Comment: @AnuragA Be careful. This determinant gives you a _signed_ area. You really need to examine its absolute value instead, although not doing so will still give you one of the solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the area using a determinant. As $x=\frac{6y-1}{7}$, you must only solve the determinant

$$\frac{1}{2}\left| det
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3 & 5 & 1 \\
   -1 & -2 & 1 \\
x & \frac{6y-1}{7} & 1
  \end{array} } \right] \right| =1
\]. $$

Solving that, you will find the $x$ and, with this valeue, it is easy fo find the $y$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Comment: Don’t you want the right-hand side to be $1$, not $0$? What your equation will find is the intersection of the line through $A$ and $B$ with $d$. Also, this determinant gives you a _signed_ area, so strictly speaking you need to examine its absolute value. Fortunately, for this problem not doing so will still give you one of the possible solutions.